# Criteria and HQL do not construct the same query

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a problem with this, but I don't know what happen. Have I a error with the query? Why return different queries?

Criteria:

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(InventoryLocationAsset.class);
result = cr.list();
```

Works fine, but with duplicated results

HQL:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM InventoryLocationAsset");
result = query.list();
```

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists

---

Criteria:

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(InventoryLocationAsset.class);
cr.fetchMode("asset", FetchMode.JOIN);
result = cr.list();
```

Works fine, but with duplicated results

HQL:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM InventoryLocationAsset _ILA JOIN FETCH _ILA.asset");
result = query.list();
```

Works fine!! (without duplicated elements)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the first HQL query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM InventoryLocationAsset");
result = query.list();
```

will become:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM " + InventoryLocationAsset.class.getName());
result = query.list();
```

In this way you'll put all path of your class.

About duplicated rows:

Your `InventoryLocationAsset` is a base class for other? If yes, check your `polimorphism` property has set (must be `explicit`)